# What could be the reason that dgrid-select Selection is not working for me?

Tags: dojo, selection, dgrid

I have this piece of code:

```
define([
 ...
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/Grid",
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/Keyboard",
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/Selection",
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/extensions/Pagination",
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider",
"MyGrid/lib/dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer",
...
], function (declare, ..., dgrid, dgridKeyboard, dgridSelection,
             dgridPagination, dgridColumnHider, dgridColumnResizer, 
             Memory, widgetTemplate) {
        ...
        // creates the grid
        _createGrid: function (columns, collection) {
            this._grid = new CustomGrid({
                className: "dgrid-autoheight",
                columns: columns,
                collection: collection,
                firstLastArrows: true,
                loadingMessage: "Loading...",
                noDataMessage: "No results.",
                pagingLinks: 2,
                pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 25],
                pagingTextBox: false,
                selectionMode: "toggle",
                allowSelectAll: true
            }, this.gridNode);
            this._grid.startup();
        },
        ...
         // Attach events to HTML dom elements
        _setupEvents: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._setupEvents");
            ...

            this._selectEventListener = this._grid.on("dgrid-select", function (event) {
                var rows, id;

            console.log(event.grid.id + ": selected " + dojoArray.map(event.rows, function (row) {
                return row.id;
            }).join(", "));
            console.log("selection: " + JSON.stringify(event.grid.selection, null, "  "));

            // Get the rows that were just selected
            rows = event.rows;

            console.log("selectionMode: " + event.grid.selectionMode);

            console.log("Row entries: " + Object.entries(rows));
            console.log("Row[0] entries: " + Object.entries(rows[0].element));
            console.log("Selection: " +  Object.entries(event.grid.selection));

                // Iterate through all currently-selected items
                for (id in event.grid.selection) {
                    if (event.grid.selection[id]) {
                        console.log("keys: " + Object.entries(event.grid.selection[id]));
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        ...
        // rerender the grid. 
        _renderGrid: function (objs) {
            var objAttributes, gridColumns;

            if (objs.length) {
                objAttributes = objs[0].getAttributes();

                if (this._grid) {
                    this._selectEventListener.remove();
                    this._errorEventListener.remove();
                    this._grid.destroy();
                    dojoConstruct.place(this.gridNode, this.domNode);
                }

                // Create header and content data.
                gridColumns = this._createColumns(objAttributes);
                this._gridStore = new Memory({
                    data: this._createData(objs, objAttributes, gridColumns)
                });
                this._createGrid(gridColumns, this._gridStore);
                this._setupEvents();
            }
        },

        // create grid HeaderData from retrieved objects.
        _createColumns: function (objAttributes) {
            var fieldname, columns, i;
            columns = [
                {field: "id", label: "ID"}
            ];

            if (objAttributes) {
                for (i in objAttributes) {
                    fieldname = objAttributes[i].toLowerCase().replace(".", "-");
                    columns.push({field: fieldname, label: objAttributes[i]});
                }
            }

            return columns;
        },
```

Selection however is really really spotty.
It only works with double-click. Below is the result of clicking on a selection:

```
dgrid_0: selected  
selection: {
  "undefined": true
}  
selectionMode: toggle  
Row entries: 0,[object Object]  
Row[0] entries: rowIndex,0  
Selection: undefined,true  
keys:
```

As you can see, it only picks up selection by event rows, not by asking grid.selection.
Multiple selections aren't picked up either.

Why is it not registering?

Comment: One of the reasons that I suspect here can be no `idProperty` in collection. There should be `id` attribute if you want to map the id of collection objects to it. If you want to map it to a different attribute, then define `idProperty: otherProperty` while creating collection.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you very much. Put your comment down as an answer and I will accept it. And this is the answer: this._gridStore = new Memory({
                    data: this._createData(objs, objAttributes, gridColumns),
                    idProperty: "id"});

Comment: Done! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons that I suspect here can be no `idProperty` in collection. There should be `id` attribute if you want to map the id of collection objects to it. If you want to map it to a different attribute, then define `idProperty: otherProperty` while creating collection.